How do I turn off Whatsdesk notifications on Ubuntu 24.04?
I have already turned them off in settings/apps/whatsdesk and actually have whatsdesk closed and no permission to run in the background, but it will still continue to disturb me every time i get a message. I want no notifications at all unless I open the app and actively go checking myself. any tips?

Sounds like you need to ask the Whatsdesk people.
